# Is there any way to remove watermark from AdobeUXImageEditorViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, adobecreativesdk, image-editor

Hello i'm using Adobe Creative SDk for image Editing.I successfully integrate it but what i want is to remove TEXT water mark below Viewcontroller "Creative Cloud Connected".

[image: In this image i mark red box that i want to remove.]

If it is possible then let me know.

Comment: Please note that this isn't allowed by the [Terms Of Service](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/legal/servicetou/Creative_SDK-en_US.pdf). Apps that remove the footer won't be able to receive a Production ID.

Comment: hi you got solution for it? I have same issue

Comment: No as per @AshRyan comment i kept that watermark